# Iteration in GEE (List Error)

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, iteration

I am writing a code that calculates the number of burned patches in a study area. The process is based on iterating over a list of numbers.

Code: [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ffarhatlokmen%2Ftests%3Atesting)

```
var country = ['ZA'];
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2013')
                      .filter(ee.Filter.inList('cc', country));
Map.centerObject(geometry, 5);

var modisFire = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1')
                  .map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry);})
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-06-01', '2017-08-01'))
                  .select('BurnDate');

var myList = ee.List.sequence(2, 50, 5);

var computeNumPatches = myList.map(function (number){
  var image = ee.Image(modisFire.toList(2).get(0)).int16();
  var patches = image.connectedPixelCount(number, true);
  patches = patches.updateMask(patches.gte(number));
  var numPatches = patches.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    scale: 500});
  return numPatches;
});

print(computeNumPatches);
```

Error Message

```
List (Error)
Image.gte, argument 'image2': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: Float. Actual value: 2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mapping over a list, you have to cast the element to the correct type before using it:

```
myList.map(function (number) {
  number = ee.Number(number)
  ...
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f50a9ea87279e8de3bc43a91dc8137ce